# Javascript API is not working inside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using third party API to get values. For example to get a country value here is the sample.

```
  var _ttprofiles = _ttprofiles || [];
   _ttprofiles.profiles = [];
   _ttprofiles.push(['_sync', false]);
   var callback = function(profiles) {

       console.log(profiles.getCountry);
   };

   _ttprofiles.push(['_registerCallback', callback]);
   _ttprofiles.push(['_enableServices']);
```

Now i am simple using in a javascript file like this.

```
 var _ttprofiles = _ttprofiles || [];
   _ttprofiles.profiles = [];
   _ttprofiles.push(['_sync', false]);
   var callback = function(profiles) {

       console.log(profiles.getCountry);
   };
   _ttprofiles.push(['_registerCallback', callback]);
   _ttprofiles.push(['_enableServices']);

   (function() {
       try {
        //   getValues();
       } catch (err) {



       }
   })();
```

I am getting values in the country. Here[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wGPI.jpg) is the screen shot of my firebug

[image]

But when i am putting this in a method then i am getting empty string

```
   (function() {
       try {
           getValues();
       } catch (err) {


       }
   })();

   function getValues()
   {
               var _ttprofiles = _ttprofiles || [];
   _ttprofiles.profiles = [];
   _ttprofiles.push(['_sync', false]);
   var callback = function(profiles) {

       console.log(profiles.getCountry);
   };
   _ttprofiles.push(['_registerCallback', callback]);
   _ttprofiles.push(['_enableServices']);


       }
```

Then i am getting empty string why? Here is the screenshot of firebug

[image]

And can someone suggest me good debugger for javascript. I am using firebug in firefox but i my console is not working i also tried chrome debugger but it has the same problem while console of firebug in chrome is working

Comment: There doesn't appear to be enough information in this question to allow a meaningful answer. What is the 3rd party API? Where does `profiles` come from?

Comment: i am using <script src="http://d.tailtarget.com/profiles.js"></script>   in my index page so profiles is coming from their

Comment: I did not understand `var _ttprofiles = _ttprofiles || [];`, from where you are getting `_ttprofiles`?

Comment: well i am using their sample which is i have defined in the question to get a country and this is how it works which is working fine but when i am putting this inside a method i am getting nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Nicolas was on to it, but you have to create a _ttprofiles variable that is in the global namespace, but rather than do that it looks like the third party library has already created that variable.  So, I tried just passing it in to your function call and it seems to be working.

I have to admit I'm not entirely sure what the output should be.  I got 'us' in the alert box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://d.tailtarget.com/profiles.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
(function() {
       try {
           getValues(_ttprofiles);
       } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
       }
   })();

function getValues(){
    _ttprofiles = _ttprofiles || [];
    _ttprofiles.profiles = [];
    _ttprofiles.push(['_sync', false]);
    var callback = function(profiles) {
        alert(profiles.getCountry);
    };
   _ttprofiles.push(['_registerCallback', callback]);
   _ttprofiles.push(['_enableServices']);
}
</script>
</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your third party maybe watch for `_ttprofiles` changes, because it's only an array and no function was call to process its content.

Try to let `_ttprofiles` global in your `getValues()` function : remove the first `var`.

Comment: what do you mean by global